# Saving state _before_ orientation change when android:configChanges="orientation" is specified

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

I have an `Activity` in my Android app that sets different layout XMLs as its view depending on the orientation. I have declared `android:configChanges="orientation"` in the manifest. Now `onConfigurationChanged()` is called - but by this time the new orientation has already taken effect.

My goal is to try to hook into the life cycle and try to save some changes **before** the new orientation is in effect; so that I can restore the state when I return to the current orientation.

I hacked it as follows, but I'm not sure if this is the right way to do this. My procedure involves saving the state in `onConfigurationChanged()` and then calling `setContentView()` to set the layout for the new orientation.

```
public class SwitchOrientationActivity extends Activity {

    private View mLandscape, mPortrait;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        mLandscape = li.inflate(R.layout.landscape, null);
        mPortrait = li.inflate(R.layout.portrait, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        if (Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE == newConfig.orientation) {
            switchToLandscape();
        } else {
            switchToPortrait();
        }
    }

    private void switchToPortrait() {

        /*
         * Use mLandscape.findViewById() to get to the views and save the values
         * I'm interested in.
         */
        saveLanscapeState();
        setContentView(mPortrait);
    }

    private void switchToLandscape() {
        /*
         * Use mPortrait.findViewById() to get to the views and save the values
         * I'm interested in.
         */
        savePortraitState();
        setContentView(mLandscape);

    }
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Since the orientation change causes the activity to be destroyed and recreated, could you always save in the onPause, onStop or onDestroy methods?

Comment: @Nick Campion: if you declare android:configChanges="orientation"  in Manifest file, activity is no longer destroyed/created upon orientation change

Comment: Ah, I learned something.

Answer (score 0):

`android:configChanges="orientation"` causes your activity to not be restarted on an orientation change, and so skips the regular lifecycle for this. I'd suggest, you take that out, then implement [onRetainNonConfigurationInstance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance%28%29)() and restore your state in either onCreate or onRestoreInstanceState. See this [article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html) for more info

Comment: Well actually, I don't need my activity to be restarted or re-created on orientation change. I want it to toggle between 2 different layouts - each offering separate functionality (portrait displays some values using graphics; landscape displays a historical chart of the values). Also, even if I were to use `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` I would still need to save Views in there, so it would introduce the risk of memory leak.